# How is the following Design option called and how can i implement it to my android app

Tags: android, filter

i want to implement a kind of filter.
Therefore i need the following input possibility:

[image]

Does somebody know how this item is called?
And how can i implement it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a SeekBar. Just drag and drop it in the design view.